# close browser context

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, playwright, playwright-java

I am using playwright and Java. On test level I have

```
List<BrowserContext> browserContexts = browser.contexts();
browserContexts.get(1).close();
```

In debug mode I have two browsers context with a difference at the url name. Now I want to prepare a method which returns int for particular url which I need to used in this test. So this method I can put in

```
browserContexts.get(nameOfThisMethod).close();
```

Url name which I want to close has "/home" in name. I don't know how to write this method which will include steps to identify url which contains /home. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into browser contexts, extract list of pages (joining into one list) and find a page, which containing url.

For example, this code do something like this

```
List<Page> result = new ArrayList<>();
browser.contexts().stream()
                    .map(BrowserContext::pages)
                    .forEach(result::addAll);
result.stream()
      .filter(p -> p.url().contains("/home"))
      .findFirst()
      .ifPresent(Page::close);
```

Example how to close page and context

```
public Optional<Page> containsUrl(List<Page> pages, String urlPart) {
        return pages.stream().filter(p -> p.url().contains(urlPart)).findFirst();
}

...

browser.contexts().stream().filter(browserContext -> containsUrl(browserContext.pages(), "/home").isPresent())
                        .findAny().ifPresent(BrowserContext::close);
```

or less nice solution

```
//in test
withoutContext(browser, "/home");

// somewhere in TestRunner or BaseTest
public void withoutContext(Browser browser, String urlPart) {
 for (BrowserContext context: browser.contexts()) {
  for(Page contextPage: context.pages()) {
    if (contextPage.url().contains(urlPart)) {
        context.close();
        break;
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I implemented this. Page with /home is now closed but the same issue when I tried to close context
'Error: Target page, context or browser has been closed

Comment: @goney225 Added second block of code to close context (closing context should also close all related pages to context).

Please, check

Comment: Unfortunately still first browser is closed too. I want to close only this browser context which has "/home" in url. I see that this url is closed but first too and error target page, context or browser has been closed is displayed

Comment: @goney225 are you sure that first url doesn't contain /home? Cause I tested this code with example.com and dou.ua by condition .ua and it closed second context and hadn't closed first.

Comment: Can you provide me your resource? Or you can debug expression and print urls in console

Comment: @goney225 added third example of code (not so nice) that also works for me. 
Also, you can easily debug it if you need

Comment: After debugging this part of code with stream is working because browser with /home in url is closed. I was wondering now why remaining part of code is not executed. I have one line code with method on click on button. It looks like this exist browser lost focus and returned "target page, context or browser has been closed"

Comment: @goney225 be sure that you execute button.click() in context that is alive. for example, try to get button from `Page page = browser.contexts()[0].pages()[0]`. 
`page.waitForSelector` ...

Comment: I used this and error about target page, context or browser has been closed
`Page page = browser.contexts().get(0).pages().get(0);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254675/discussion-between-goney225-and-yaroslavm).